# Need to use different APK Version Code, but actually has not been used

Tags: android, react-native, versioning, release, beta

I publish my app about 1 year ago with version code 10005. And now I upload again with version code 10505 and I got this message:

this is the screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GJuW7.jpg 
(sorry I haven't reached 10 reputations to be able to attach image here.

I have searched for version code 10005 in my code. And even that screenshot shows 10505 has already been used, that actually hasn't

How can I solve this?

this is my default config:

```
defaultConfig {
    /* another */
    versionCode codeVersion
    versionName "${versionMajor}.${versionMinor}.${versionPatch}-${releaseType}"
    /* another */
}
```

And this is what codeVersion, versionMajor Minor Patch and releaseType origin:

```
subprojects {
    ext {
        def npmVersion = getNpmVersionArray()
        versionMajor = npmVersion[0]
        versionMinor = npmVersion[1]
        versionPatch = npmVersion[2]
        codeVersion = npmVersion[3]
        releaseType = System.env.RELEASE_TYPE != null ? System.env.RELEASE_TYPE : ''
    }

    afterEvaluate {project ->
        if (project.hasProperty("android")) {
            android {
                compileSdkVersion 26
                buildToolsVersion '26.0.3'
            }
        }
    }

    if (project.name.contains('react-native-image-picker')) {
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }

    if (project.name.contains('react-native-vector-icons')) {
        buildscript {
            repositories {
                jcenter()
                maven { url "https://dl.bintray.com/android/android-tools/"  }
            }
        }
    }
}

def getNpmVersion() {
    def inputFile = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/android/" + "version.json")
    def packageJson = new JsonSlurper().parseText(inputFile.text)

    return packageJson
}

def getNpmVersionArray() { // major [0], minor [1], patch [2]
    def jsonData = getNpmVersion()
    def (major, minor, patch) = jsonData["version"].tokenize('.')
    def code = jsonData["code"]

    def releaseType = System.env.RELEASE_TYPE != null ? System.env.RELEASE_TYPE : ''

    println "Building version: ${major}.${minor}.${patch}-${releaseType}; Version code: ${code}"

    return [Integer.parseInt(major), Integer.parseInt(minor), Integer.parseInt(patch), Integer.parseInt(code)] as int[]
}
```

So actually the flow is fetching this version.json:

```
{
  "version": "1.5.5",
  "code": "10505"
}
```

And then use it to define versionCode and versionName in build.gradle

Comment: what is your app version code ? check version code from build.gradle(Module:add) file on the top

Comment: you might have already added apk but not published it, check if you have any releases pending.

Comment: I've deleted the last app release and add new release, upload with different version (1.5.6) and still got the same message: https://i.imgur.com/QXBQSA9.png